# Конвертация в json javascript

Tags: javascript

```
var s = [];
for(var row = 0 in data.Rows) {
    var arr = [];
    arr.name = row;
    arr.data = data.Rows[row];
    s.push(arr);
}
console.log(s);
console.log(JSON.stringify(s));
```

Почему данный код выводит пустой JSON?

скрин:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: потому что в массиве сериализуются только числовые свойства